# Mysql - query fields that end like search term

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table like this in MySql:

```
ID | suffix
1  | .com
2  | .co.uk
3  | .co.to
```

Is there any way, short of using a stored procedures, to design a query that will return all matches to a query string like this: `example.com`. It is important that it only matches if it matches with the end of the given string.

Example:

- `example.com` matches `.com`
- `example.co.uk.com` also matches `.com` and does NOT match `.co.uk`

Comment: Does the query string has a single dot (`.`) always?

Comment: No, a query string could be a complete url including subdomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 'example.com' like concat('%', t.suffix);
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. I can give you the best answer in about 11 minutes.